# Can't get PIL to support any images

Tags: python-imaging-library, libjpeg, ubuntu-11.10

After installing PIL with pip install PIL under Ubuntu 11.10, the summary tells me "not available" on all items.

I've read through several "answers" like
http://obroll.com/install-python-pil-python-image-library-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/

which essentially tells me the same thing: Install PIL after libjpeg.

I still can't get it to work.
(I'm a novice with ubuntu)

Any ideas?

Copy/Paste from the summary:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08)

              [GCC 4.6.1]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
*** JPEG support not available
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finaly got it working.
My experience was that even though I installed in the correct order, PIL still could not find libjpeg.

What I did:

1. make sure libjpeg8 and libjpeg8-dev is installed and find out where it is installed with "locate libjpeg"
2. pip install --no-install PIL" -> downloads the install files
3. edit setup.py from the virtual environment's build directory and set JPEG_ROOT. In my case: JPEG_ROOT = "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/"
4. "pip install PIL" -> will now install PIL with the modified setup.py and find the libjpeg.

Answer (score 1):

PIL works on my machine. My possibly relevant installed packages (`dpkg --get-selections | grep jpg`) are:

```
libjpeg-progs
libjpeg62
libjpeg62:i386
libjpeg62-dev
libjpeg8
libmjpegtools-1.9
libopenjpeg2
```

So you could try just installing the lot and reinstalling PIL. Not a very insightful answer I'm afraid.

Comment: Still no luck here. dpkg shows the libjpeg's I need. I've also created soft-links as described at http://jj.isgeek.net/2011/09/install-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-ubuntu-oneiric-64bits/ (but for my correct 32 bit installation).